# Change spring boot embedded web server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, undertow

How can I change spring boot default web server?
And for complicated business and big transactions which one has the best performance?

I need a KPI for spring boot web server assessment.

Answer (score 1):

1. for how to change embedded web server, checkout the official 'how-to' guide:
   [Embedded Web Servers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.webserver).
2. for performance assessment, checkout this sharing. [SpringBoot — performance testing various Embedded Web Servers](https://medium.com/@skhatri.dev/springboot-performance-testing-various-embedded-web-servers-7d460bbfdb1b).